# How do I check if keyboard keys and/or LEDs on the keyboard are functioning correctly?

Tags: windows, keyboard

I would like to check if all the keys and LEDs on a keyboard are functioning correctly. e.g. Check if a key does not respond (or responds late) to a keypress,  activates even when it isn't pressed, does not respond to multiple keys pressed at the same time, among other possible keyboard issues not readily apparent.

I would like to get an indication that can show when the keyboard registers a pressed key, to make it easier to troubleshoot faulty keys. [This shareware program](http://www.passmark.com/products/keytest.htm) does that, but it's a 30-day trial only and I prefer a freeware alternative or one that doesn't have a similar functionality limitation.

The OS I am using is Windows 7.

Comment: Yes — "Notepad" :)

Comment: @jtbandes Doh! :) I will edit my question to make it clearer the I prefer one with a GUI that can make it easy to spot faulty keys.